# Why the regression line calculated point is not same as the graph?

Tags: excel

```
2007    2138255.39 2008 1670868.97 2009 1416132.03 2010 1567135.26 2011 1736225.1 2012
```

I want to calculate when x = 2012. In the graph the estimated point is bigger than 2000000. However, when I calculate this point it shows negative. Does anyone know why this happens?

[image: screenshot is here]

Comment: 2007 2138255.39
2008 1670868.97
2009 1416132.03
2010 1567135.26
2011 1736225.1
2012

Comment: That belongs in the question itself. You can edit it in. Also, it looks like you missed the tail end of the data.

Comment: Your regression is numerically unstable. You could measure time in years since 2000 and divide each of the y-values by 1e6 (so that the unit is 1 million) and then see what you get.